# List of supported guest OSes of VMware Server

Tags: vmware, virtualization

Where can I find a list of the guest OSes that VMware Server supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VMWare Server release notes](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmserver2.pdf) list Supported Guest Operating Systems for VMWare Server 2.0.2 on page 31ff.:

#### Windows 64-Bit Operating Systems

- Windows Server 2008 x64 Standard Edition
- Windows Server 2008 x64 Enterprise Edition
- Windows Vista x64 Business Edition
- Windows Vista x64 Ultimate Edition
- Windows XP Professional x64
- Windows Server 2003 x64 Standard Edition
- Windows Server 2003 x64 Web Edition
- Windows Server 2003 x64 Enterprise Edition

#### Windows 32-Bit Guest Operating Systems

- Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition
- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition
- Windows Vista Business Edition
- Windows Vista Ultimate Edition
- Windows XP Professional
- Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition
- Windows Server 2003 Web Edition
- Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition
- Windows Small Business Server 2003 Standard Edition
- Windows Small Business Server 2003 Premium Edition
- Windows 2000 Server
- Windows 2000 Advanced Server

#### Linux 64-Bit Guest Operating Systems

- Mandrake Linux
- Mandriva Linux
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux
- SUSE Linux
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server
- openSUSE Linux
- Open Enterprise Server (OES)
- Ubuntu Linux

#### Linux 32-Bit Guest Operating Systems

- Mandrake Linux
- Mandriva Linux
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux
- SUSE Linux
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server
- openSUSE Linux
- Open Enterprise Server (OES)
- Ubuntu Linux

#### Others

- Solaris x86
- Novell NetWare NetWare